# trouble deploying node.js app to heroku because of hard coded port number

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am having trouble deploying the angular-seed app (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) to Heroku. I believe the problem to be that the port number is hard coded into the server starting scripts when heroku needs to dynamically assign the port through the process.env.PORT variable. Looking through the heroku logs confirms that: `Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 8000`. My Procfile contains `web: npm start`, and my package.json file contains

```
"scripts": {
  "prestart": "npm install",
  "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"
}
```

How can I change that so that my server will still work properly in a local dev environment with `foreman start`, however dynamically assign a port when using heroku? I want it so that when I type `foreman start` on my local dev environment, a server will be created at localhost:8000, but when I deploy the app to heroku, the port will be chosen by Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the same issue. So far got it resolved with help of express.

1. Added Procfile:

   ```
   web: node web.js
   ```
2. Added web.js

   ```
   var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 8000);

   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
   var server = app.listen(port, function() {
       console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
   });
   ```
3. Added `"express": "3.x"` in dependencies section of package.json
4. Replaced

   ```
   "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"
   ```

   with

   ```
   "start": "node web.js"
   ```
5. Then commit, run `git push heroku master` and after it finishes `heroku open`

Comment: You helped me deploy my first web app with this fix. Cheers, fine sir :)

Answer (score 6):

I am not a Node developer, but why don't you use the PORT number provisioned by Heroku in your `start` script?

ie. `"start": "http-server -a localhost -p $PORT"`

Then it will run on Heroku.  If you're running locally, just `export PORT=8000`, or put `PORT=8000` in your `.env` file if you run using `foreman`, and you're good to go.

You can also probably add bash magic to set a PORT if none is set by replacing `$PORT` with `${PORT-8000}`.

(Untested)

Comment: I just tested. Nice. I am happy you can actually do that. I was worried it wouldn't work inside the json file.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to solve it without express, using only node `http-server` module, here what you need in your `package.json` :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server ./ -p ${PORT:=5000} -c-1"
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

- Added `http-server`in your dependencies (should not be in dev dependencies)
- `-p ${PORT:=8000}`binds the server to the port available for you heroku instance which is found on the environment variable. If no environement variable exists with that name (e.g. locally) it defaults to `8000`
- Removed the `-a localhost`which is not compatible with heroku